# Mongoose cannot read property of undefined with complex schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have the following user schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
         email: String,
         password: String
    },
    education: {
        school: {
            start: Boolean,
            name: String,
            graduationYear: String
        },
        college: {
            start: Boolean,
            name: String,
            career: String,
            enterYear: String,
            graduationYear: String
        }
    }
});
```

Now, when I submit a form with all of this information, my app routes the POST request to the following function:

```
exports.postEditEducation = function (req, res){
    process.nextTick(function (){
        var user = req.user;

        user.education.school.start = req.body.schoolStart;
        user.education.school.name = req.body.schoolName;
        user.education.school.graduationYear = req.body.graduationYear;

        user.education.college.start = req.body.collegeStart;
        user.education.college.name = req.body.collegeName;
        user.education.college.career = req.body.collegeCareer;
        user.education.college.enterYear = req.body.collegeEnterYear;
        user.education.college.graduationYear = req.body.collegeGraduationYear;

        user.save(function (err){
            if (err)
                throw err;

            res.redirect('/profile');
        });
    });
};
```

But, when I submit the information the following error appears:

```
user.education.college.start = req.body.collegeStart;
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'start' of undefined
    at /file.js:464:46
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var user = req.user;
```

you have created variable for the holding the req.user

```
 user.education.college.start
```

To do this you should create a user collection instance. Create some instance for the userschema. 
For example i assume userschema's collection name as usercollection:

```
var userobj = new usercollection(); 
userobj.education.college.start = req.body.schoolStart; ..
```

Hope this may be useful.

Comment: Actually, this does not help me at all, as I'm using passport to authenticate the user, so I can retrieve the user from the request with req.user. My problem is that I can set all of the school properties, but not the college ones